# How to enable the RTF editor in Jira

Tags: jira, confluence

I'm new to Jira and have big problem with creating tables inside my testing plan. Using pipes, double pipes, etc. to build the table markup is really time consuming.

So, I saw here, that actually there's a RTF editor with visual table building in Confluence (which should be used in JIRA right? ) : http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Working+with+Tables+in+the+Rich+Text+Editor

However the textareas in my Jira installation are just plain text fields and can't figure out how to turn them into the the nice RTF areas shown in the URL above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go to Admin, Field Configurations and tell JIRA to use the Wiki Renderer for fields such as Description and Environment.

Comment: turned out our Jira does not have Confluence installed, but if we had it that's the answer indeed :)

Comment: Holy crap, how did I miss this feature? Must have snuck it in 4.0.

Comment: Been there for years, but it's one of those tucked away things. You might even be able to use different renderers for different field configuration schemes if you want to get fancy.